# Не пойму в чем ошибка

Tags: python

Сегодня в N часов M минут хозяин магазина заказал доставку нового товара. Оператор сказал, что продукты доставят через T минут.
Сколько будет времени на электронных часах, когда привезут долгожданные продукты?
Написал к задаче вот такой код но яндекс его не засчитывает

```
hour = int(input())
minute = int(input())
duration = int(input())


def whatTime(a, b, c) :
    hour = a
    minute = b
    duration_hours = c // 60
    duration_minutes = c % 60
    hour += duration_hours
    minute += duration_minutes
    if minute > 60:
        hour += 1
        minute -= 60
    while hour > 24:
        hour -= 24
    if hour < 10:
        if minute < 10:
            time = f'0{hour}:0{minute}'
        else:
            time = f'0{hour}:{minute}'
    elif minute < 10:
        time = f'{hour}:0{minute}'
    else:
        time = f'{hour}:{minute}'
    return time


print(whatTime(hour, minute, duration))
```

Comment: Какие-нибудь уточнения есть, почему не засчитывает? Неверный ответ, таймаут выполнения, ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка: `a=23, b=0, c=60` программа напечатает `24:00` (!).

Поменяйте условие `hour > 24` на `hour >= 24`.

Программу можно сократить в вычислениях и в форматировании:

```
def whatTime(a, b, c):
    h = (a + (b + c) // 60) % 24
    m = (b + c) % 60
    return f'{h:02}:{m:02}'


print(whatTime(int(input()), int(input()), int(input())))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал вот так:

```
def new_time(hour: int, minute: int, duration: int) -> str:

    new_hour = (hour + (minute + duration) // 60) % 24
    new_minute = (minute + duration) % 60

    return f'{new_hour:0>2}:{new_minute:0>2}'
```

Тут мы используем встроенную фичу форматирования строк

Comment: Что не так, у меня там порядок выражений полетел?

Comment: А, все вижу) Спасибо, что подметил!